# VB.Net - Adwords API Get Domain Keywords, CPC And Search Volume

Tags: vb.net, api, keyword, google-ads-api

**Function 1:**

```
Public Function DomainKeywords(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim output As String = ""
    Dim user As AdWordsUser = New AdWordsUser
    Using targetingIdeaService As TargetingIdeaService = CType(user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201710.TargetingIdeaService), TargetingIdeaService)
        Dim selector As New TargetingIdeaSelector()
        selector.requestType = RequestType.IDEAS
        selector.ideaType = IdeaType.KEYWORD
        selector.requestedAttributeTypes = New AttributeType() {AttributeType.KEYWORD_TEXT, AttributeType.SEARCH_VOLUME, AttributeType.AVERAGE_CPC, AttributeType.CATEGORY_PRODUCTS_AND_SERVICES}
        Dim searchParameters As New List(Of SearchParameter)
        Dim relatedToUrlSearchParameter As New RelatedToUrlSearchParameter
        relatedToUrlSearchParameter.urls = New String() {url}
        relatedToUrlSearchParameter.includeSubUrls = False
        searchParameters.Add(relatedToUrlSearchParameter)
        Dim languageParameter As New LanguageSearchParameter()
        Dim hebrew As New Language()
        hebrew.id = 1027
        languageParameter.languages = New Language() {hebrew}
        searchParameters.Add(languageParameter)
        Dim locationParameter As New LocationSearchParameter()
        Dim israel As New Location
        israel.id = 2376
        locationParameter.locations = New Location() {israel}
        searchParameters.Add(locationParameter)
        selector.searchParameters = searchParameters.ToArray()
        selector.paging = New Paging
        Dim page As New TargetingIdeaPage()
        Dim offset As Integer = 0
        Dim pageSize As Integer = 180
        Try
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            Do
                selector.paging.startIndex = offset
                selector.paging.numberResults = pageSize
                page = targetingIdeaService.get(selector)
                Dim keywordCheck As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
                If Not page.entries Is Nothing AndAlso page.entries.Length > 0 Then
                    For Each targetingIdea As TargetingIdea In page.entries
                        For Each entry As Type_AttributeMapEntry In targetingIdea.data
                            Dim ideas As Dictionary(Of AttributeType, AdWords.v201710.Attribute) = MapEntryExtensions.ToDict(Of AttributeType, AdWords.v201710.Attribute)(targetingIdea.data)
                            Dim keyword As String = DirectCast(ideas(AttributeType.KEYWORD_TEXT), StringAttribute).value
                            Dim averageMonthlySearches As Long = DirectCast(ideas(AttributeType.SEARCH_VOLUME), LongAttribute).value
                            '''''''''''''''''''This Returns a Wrong Number
                            Dim cpc As Money = DirectCast(ideas(AttributeType.AVERAGE_CPC), MoneyAttribute).value
                            Dim microedit As String = Math.Round(cpc.microAmount / 1000000, 2).ToString + "$"
                            ''''''''''''''''''
                            Dim isExist As Boolean = False
                            For Each keycheck In keywordCheck
                                If keyword = keycheck Then
                                    isExist = True
                                End If
                            Next
                            If isExist = False Then
                                keywordCheck.Add(keyword)
                                If output = String.Empty Then
                                    output = keyword + "@@@" + microedit + "@@@" + averageMonthlySearches.ToString
                                Else
                                    output = output + Environment.NewLine + keyword + "@@@" + microedit + "@@@" + averageMonthlySearches.ToString
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                        i = i + 1
                    Next
                End If
                offset = offset + pageSize
            Loop While (offset < page.totalNumEntries)
        Catch e As Exception
            If output = String.Empty Then
                output = "ERROR"
                If e.Message.Contains("Rate exceeded") Then
                    MsgBox("rate exceeded")
                Else
                    MsgBox(e.Message.ToString)
                End If
            End If
        End Try
    End Using
    Return output
End Function
```

This function gets a url as input and returns keywords that relevant to that url as output in the following format:

**KeywordName1@@@CPC@@@SearchVolume**
**KeywordName2@@@CPC@@@SearchVolume**

for some reason no matter what website I type in it returns 180 results,

**Im aware that pageSize is set to 180**,
In-fact if you lower pageSize to 179, you only get 179 results, the problem is that i cant get **more** then 180 results whatsoever..

---

**Optional help:** also why the CPC value returned in the first function is different from the CPC value returned from that function:

**Function 2:**

```
Public Function KeywordCPC(keyName As String, Optional Tries As Integer = 0) As String
    Dim output As String = ""
    Dim user As AdWordsUser = New AdWordsUser
    Using trafficEstimatorService As TrafficEstimatorService = CType(user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201710.TrafficEstimatorService), TrafficEstimatorService)
        Dim keyword3 As New Keyword
        keyword3.text = keyName
        keyword3.matchType = KeywordMatchType.EXACT
        Dim keywords As Keyword() = New Keyword() {keyword3}
        Dim keywordEstimateRequests As New List(Of KeywordEstimateRequest)
        For Each keyword As Keyword In keywords
            Dim keywordEstimateRequest As New KeywordEstimateRequest
            keywordEstimateRequest.keyword = keyword
            keywordEstimateRequests.Add(keywordEstimateRequest)
        Next
        Dim adGroupEstimateRequest As New AdGroupEstimateRequest
        adGroupEstimateRequest.keywordEstimateRequests = keywordEstimateRequests.ToArray
        adGroupEstimateRequest.maxCpc = New Money
        adGroupEstimateRequest.maxCpc.microAmount = 1000000
        Dim campaignEstimateRequest As New CampaignEstimateRequest
        campaignEstimateRequest.adGroupEstimateRequests = New AdGroupEstimateRequest() {adGroupEstimateRequest}
        Dim countryCriterion As New Location
        countryCriterion.id = 2376
        Dim languageCriterion As New Language
        languageCriterion.id = 1027
        campaignEstimateRequest.criteria = New Criterion() {countryCriterion, languageCriterion}
        Try
            Dim selector As New TrafficEstimatorSelector
            selector.campaignEstimateRequests = New CampaignEstimateRequest() {campaignEstimateRequest}
            selector.platformEstimateRequested = False
            Dim result As TrafficEstimatorResult = trafficEstimatorService.get(selector)
            If ((Not result Is Nothing) AndAlso (Not result.campaignEstimates Is Nothing) AndAlso (result.campaignEstimates.Length > 0)) Then
                Dim campaignEstimate As CampaignEstimate = result.campaignEstimates(0)
                If ((Not campaignEstimate.adGroupEstimates Is Nothing) AndAlso (campaignEstimate.adGroupEstimates.Length > 0)) Then
                    Dim adGroupEstimate As AdGroupEstimate = campaignEstimate.adGroupEstimates(0)
                    If (Not adGroupEstimate.keywordEstimates Is Nothing) Then
                        For i As Integer = 0 To adGroupEstimate.keywordEstimates.Length - 1
                            Dim keyword As Keyword = keywordEstimateRequests.Item(i).keyword
                            Dim keywordEstimate As KeywordEstimate = adGroupEstimate.keywordEstimates(i)
                            If keywordEstimateRequests.Item(i).isNegative Then
                                Continue For
                            End If
                            Dim meanAverageCpc As Long = 0L
                            Dim meanAveragePosition As Double = 0
                            Dim meanClicks As Single = 0
                            Dim meanTotalCost As Single = 0
                            If (Not (keywordEstimate.min Is Nothing) AndAlso Not (keywordEstimate.max Is Nothing)) Then
                                If (Not (keywordEstimate.min.averageCpc Is Nothing) AndAlso Not (keywordEstimate.max.averageCpc Is Nothing)) Then
                                    meanAverageCpc = CLng((keywordEstimate.min.averageCpc.microAmount + keywordEstimate.max.averageCpc.microAmount) / 2)
                                End If
                            End If
                            output = Math.Round(meanAverageCpc / 1000000, 2).ToString + "$"
                        Next i
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                output = "ZERO"
            End If
        Catch e As Exception
            If output = String.Empty Then
                output = "ERROR"
                If e.Message.Contains("Rate exceeded") Then
                    output = KeywordCPC(keyName, Tries + 1)
                End If
            End If
        End Try
    End Using
    Return output
End Function
```

how can I get EXCAT CPC in the first function?

> because now only the **second function return good CPC** and the
>   **first function return the wrong CPC(checked in israeli adwords frontend)**

---

**If you want to know how to use the functions (for beginners):**
[VB.Net - Trying To Increase the efficiency of adwords API requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483694/vb-net-trying-to-increase-the-efficiency-of-adwords-api-requests)

Comment: Thanks for reading and perhaps helping :) good day. short as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.Net - Trying To Increase the efficiency of adwords API requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483694/vb-net-trying-to-increase-the-efficiency-of-adwords-api-requests)

Comment: @OrrBurgel - Please don't link to external sites. Doing so reduces the value of the question as the linked code may change or the links may break. Also, "short as possible" isn't the same as "minimal". You should provide a [mcve]. You need to make the effort to reduce the code to the minimal amount required to demonstrate the issue. You're previous question was closed because you didn't do that. This one probably will be to unless you can fix it. Please don't assume I'm being rude or mean - I'm trying to help you to ask a quality question. That's the job of members of this community.

Comment: The only problem is that the code is minimal, how can you solve it without knowing which class of adwords api I use, for what reason you close this one, please tell me excatly what I did wrong because I cant minimize it even more without deleting necessary information.....

Comment: its not a duplicate.. no one read what i write here :(